# AWS EC2 instance - Can access instance using old ssh key even after changing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, server, ubuntu-18.04

Recently, I had to change ssh key of my EC2 instance which i did using following steps:

1. Created new key-pair file from AWS
2. Connected to AWS using old ssh and then went to .ssh directory listed under root folder.
3. Opened authorized_keys file and deleted old key from there and added new PRIVATE key and then saved it.
4. Restarted ssh service.
5. Opened new terminal and tried to connect using new ssh key and it worked without any issue.

However, my problem is that when I tried to connect using old ssh which I just removed from `authorized_keys` file, I was able to connect to server which I did not want.

Can anybody explain me if I doing anything wrong here as I wanted to remove access of server via old ssh key and use only new ssh key?

Comment: You should have added not the public key, not the private key, but the public openssh fingerprint format of your key.

Comment: What you describe should not be possible. If the matching keypair is not in the user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, it should not be possible to login.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, created new pem key from amazon console, generated rsa pub file from pem file. Replaced the rsa key in authorized_keys file on the ec2. Restart ssh service, can access with new key but I can also access with old key